# Map network drive permanently

Tags: windows, powershell, networking

How to change this script so netrwork drive is still aviable after machine reboot?

```
$User = "user"
$PWord = ConvertTo-SecureString -String "password" -AsPlainText -Force
$Credential = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $User, $PWord 
$net = $(New-Object -ComObject WScript.Network)
$net.MapNetworkDrive("r:", "\\name\othername")
```

Answer (score 1):

Powershells way:

```
New-PSDrive -Name "R" -PSProvider FileSystem -Root "\\name\othername" -persist:$true -Scope Global
```

Comment: and how can i use login and password?

Comment: It supports a Parameter for credentials, so just add `-Credential`. Run `Help New-PSDrive` to get the syntax for it

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
net use r: \\name\othername
```